# What is the best way to go about high-quality wireless communication between two microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, pcb, digital-logic

I want to sample a wave from a record player with a very high-bitrate using an analog to digital converter which gets sent to a microcontroller. That microcontroller then sends the wave at a high-bitrate to another microcontroller via a wireless communication at a short distance. The signal then gets sent through a digital to analog converter and then to a stereo and respective speakers. I am looking for guidance as to where to start researching for a high-quality wireless transmission, because some of the wireless protocols ( like bluetooth ) I was looking at have limitations that degrade a sound wave too much. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using digital? Why not analog FM? I think it would be much simpler.

Comment: I found a crazy solution: transmit raw S/PDIF over NTSC video band: http://www.latentlaboratories.com/blog/2014/10/11/12-wireless-lossless-digital-audio . Although I would personally prefer some kind of 2.4G solution, and if fact if you search for "spdif 2.4GHz" you can find quite a few off-the-shelf solutions, and believe they are based on some single-chip suction from TI or AD.

Comment: It's for my senior project, and I want to create an interesting solution and not just a few rlc circuits, but I do agree it would be easier.

Comment: You need to consider latency, buffering across radio interference, and deriving a sample clock (or fractional sample rate conversion) on the receiver side before you go very far.  There are router-chipset derived wifi solutions for this, 2.4 GHz solutions... and indeed shipping S/PDIF over analog video links - each of these will have different response to interference.

Comment: The Nordic Semi modules would be my first choice for this.

Comment: Bit rate? MP3 or full CD quality? Stereo? Distance? Power? Streaming or full handshake? Error correction? Optical or radio? Do some work and fill in the gaps (at least to your own satisfaction) then come back with a better list of requirements.

Comment: @Cyberiankhatru What makes you think using Bluetooth will degrade quality?

Answer (score 1):

There are really a lot of ways to accomplish what you want to do, but I understand that what you are looking for is guidance on how to structure your search to get things done.

As you have an idea of what you want your system to do at a high level, I would start working down to the technical specifications. As you are now trying to find a good wireless transmission module, I would recommend taking a step back and defining exactly what you mean by "very high bitrate". You could use lossless compression to push part of the burden to the microcontrollers, but if you don't want to do that, you need to calculate what is the maximum data throughput you will need from your wireless system. Keep in mind that requirements such as error checking and real-time streaming could also affect the number of bytes you need to transmit.

With that said, there are many readily available modules that will allow you to transfer data at high speed, but keep in mind the trade-offs between power, speed, protocol complexity and the cost of your design.

If you want to elaborate a bit more and give more specific requirements for the radio module you are seeking, I'm sure you will receive more effective suggestions about which module to use.

Answer (score 0):

A few.

1. Use high quality hardware and software that is compatible with your existing components.
2. Use them in a really quiet and electromegnetically clean environment
3. Use them as closely as possible.
4. Use them at the slowest possible speed.
5. Use them with high quality power supply.

...

Just to get you started.